# Incorporating Python script into ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder, python-script-tool

Within ModelBuilder in ArcGIS, I am trying to add a script that will randomly assign "model types" (which is text) into the new field I have created in the attribute table. I checked to make sure the whole model ran without any problems before adding the script. The script has ran without any errors as well, but from the python window within ArcGIS.

Does anyone know the proper way to add this script to the model?

[image]

Comment: You should be able to integrate the Model Type python script into the model the same as any of the other geoprocessing tools...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a link to the Esri guide on [adding a python script to a model](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/modelbuilder/integrating-scripts-within-a-model.htm). Essentially you can just navigate to the python script tool in Catalog, then drag and drop it into the model. You will need to make some [configuration selections first, though](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/modelbuilder/integrating-scripts-within-a-model.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_2931CAD4724A49EB8DE48177B3247C42) (it appears you're missing that step), so read that guide.